# How to keep DIVs from changing position after reboot?

Tags: html, css, webforms

I've got question. I created my first WebForms Application. Now I am on my way to create Site.Master 
(toolbar). So I write Menu from DevExpress controls, didn't change anything in Site.css and I have something that I can't understand.

When I run project via Chrome my Toolbar looks like:

[div class float-left][div class float-left]        [div class float-right]

But when I reboot PC, run project again (compile), my Toolbar looks like:

[div class float-left]              [div class float-right]

[div class float-left]

I have to delete my cache from Chrome and then everything is ok.

## This is code for Site.Master:

```
        <div class="float-right">
            <dx:ASPxMenu ID="ASPxLogin" runat="server" Theme="Moderno" Font-Size="Small" Cursor="pointer" ShowAsToolbar="True">
                <Paddings PaddingLeft="3px" PaddingRight="3px" />
                <Items>
                    <dx:MenuItem Text="0" Enabled="False">
                        <Image Url="~/Images/Controls/btn-profile-black.png" UrlHottracked="~/Images/Controlsbtn-profile-white.png" UrlDisabled="~/Images/Controls/btn-profile-grey.png" />
                        <ItemStyle BackColor="Aqua" Font-Size="Small"></ItemStyle>
                    </dx:MenuItem>
                    <dx:MenuItem Text="A">
                        <Image Url="~/Images/Controls/btn-off-white.png" UrlDisabled="~/Images/Controls/btn-off-grey.png">
                        </Image>
                        <ItemStyle BackColor="#E06666" ForeColor="White">
                            <HoverStyle BackColor="#970000">
                            </HoverStyle>
                        </ItemStyle>
                    </dx:MenuItem>
                </Items>
            </dx:ASPxMenu>
        </div>

    <div class="float-left">
        <dx:ASPxMenu ID="ASPxMenu" runat="server" Theme="Moderno" Font-Size="Small" Cursor="pointer" ShowAsToolbar="True">
            <Paddings PaddingLeft="3px" PaddingRight="3px" />
            <Items>
                <dx:MenuItem Text=" ">
                    <Image Url="~/Images/logo.jpg" Height="32px"></Image>
                    <ItemStyle BackColor="White">
                        <HoverStyle BackColor="White">
                        </HoverStyle>

                    </ItemStyle>
                    <SubMenuStyle BackColor="#CC0000" />
                </dx:MenuItem>
                <dx:MenuItem Text="B">
                    <Image Url="~/Images/Controls/btn-home-black.png" UrlDisabled="~/Images/Controls/btn-home-grey.png" UrlHottracked="~/Images/Controls/btn-home-white.png" />

                    <ItemStyle BackColor="Aqua">

                        <HoverStyle BackColor="Black">
                        </HoverStyle>
                    </ItemStyle>

                </dx:MenuItem>
            </Items>
        </dx:ASPxMenu>
    </div>

    <div class="float-left">
        <dx:ASPxMenu ID="ASPxMenu1" runat="server" Theme="Moderno" Font-Size="Small" Cursor="pointer" ShowAsToolbar="True">
            <Paddings PaddingLeft="3px" PaddingRight="3px" />
            <Items>
                <dx:MenuItem Text="C" BeginGroup="True">
                    <Image Url="~/Images/Controls/btn-view-black.png" UrlDisabled="~/Images/Controls/btn-view-grey.png" UrlHottracked="~/Images/Controls/btn-view-white.png">
                    </Image>
                    <ItemStyle BackColor="Aqua">

                        <HoverStyle BackColor="Black">
                        </HoverStyle>
                    </ItemStyle>
                </dx:MenuItem>
                <dx:MenuItem Text="F">
                    <Image Url="~/Images/Controls/btn-add-black.png" UrlDisabled="~/Images/Controls/btn-add-grey.png" UrlHottracked="~/Images/Controls/btn-add-white.png">
                    </Image>
                    <ItemStyle BackColor="#B6D7A8">
                        <HoverStyle BackColor="#009900">
                        </HoverStyle>

                    </ItemStyle>
                </dx:MenuItem>
                <dx:MenuItem Text="R">
                    <Image Url="~/Images/Controls/btn-bin-white.png" UrlDisabled="~/Images/Controls/btn-bin-grey.png">
                    </Image>
                    <ItemStyle BackColor="#E06666" ForeColor="White">
                        <HoverStyle BackColor="#970000">
                        </HoverStyle>

                    </ItemStyle>
                </dx:MenuItem>
            </Items>
        </dx:ASPxMenu>
    </div>
```

## This is code for Site.css:

```
header, footer, hgroup,
nav, section {
    display: block;
}

mark {
    background-color: #a6dbed;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
}

.float-left {
    float: left;
}

.float-right {
    float: right;
}
```

Comment: How are ur `divs` changing position? And in ur HTML there is no `flot-right` div.

Comment: Well I update my question because I didn't put new line, and also add float-right div in code.

Comment: replace the order of ur `divs` , place `float-right` at the end.

Comment: Even if it works, how it's connected with cleaning cache in browser?

Comment: To clear the cache so that your older `css` won't stay.

Comment: Well, the point is that when I ll reboot my PC, open VS again and compile project divs will change positions. I mean there wont be Toolbar in a row, but Toolbar will go from Top to Bottom. Then I ll have to clean my cache on browser and compile again = everything gonna be ok.